# Adding Grid Serializer of a custom module into a custom product tab

Tags: magento

I am new to Magento. I have made a custom module named "Custom_Press" using module creator and I customized it little bit. Its working fine.

Following are the fields in the form of my module.

1. Press Title
2. Press Image
3. Press Date
4. Press Thumbnail
5. Status

I want to show all of its data in a grid serializer in a custom product tab. So that any press can be selected from the grid serializer against any product like the default magento functionality of upsell and cross-sells product's grid serializer.

Comment: Just a recommendation here. If you are using module creators give this a try http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/utilities/developer-tools/ultimate-modulecreator-8949.html. It has built in a feature that does exactly what you need. (I hope this is not considered self-promotion. I've created the tool but I get no financial benefits from it.)

Answer (score 1):

you need to add new tab to Tabs block 'Namespace/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Form/Edit/Tabs.php':

```
$product_content = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('module/adminhtml_form_edit_tab_product', 'adminform_products.grid')->toHtml();
$serialize_block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_grid_serializer');
$serialize_block->initSerializerBlock('adminform_products.grid', 'getSelectedProducts', 'products', 'selected_products');
$serialize_block->addColumnInputName('position');
$product_content .= $serialize_block->toHtml();
$this->addTab('associated_products', array(
'label' => Mage::helper('module')->__('Products'),
'title' => Mage::helper('module')->__('Products'),
'content' => $product_content
));
```

The serializer is most important feature which allow you to define fields which will be editable in the grid, and define a name parameter which you should see in Save action of the form.

For more details please have a look at -
http://turnkeye.com/blog/magento-admin-form/